# I can't get the origin of the request in tidhttpServer

Tags: delphi, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm trying to get the `Origin` of a request in a `TIdHTTPServer`, but all I see that I have access to is `Host`.

Since it's Delphi, I thought they may set `Host` of the request, so if I do this:

```
s := ARequestInfo.Host;
```

I'll get the Host being it's Origin. But no, `Host` is me, as in a normal world.

But, for some reason, they didn't make an `Origin` property, so I don't know how to get it, and I need to know the Origin to make my response.

I tried getting the origin with:

```
s := ARequestInfo.CustomHeaders.Values['Origin'];
```

But it's empty.

I see in the browser's request that the Origin is `localhost` or null.

This is my procedure that manages the requests:

```
procedure TRestService.commandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var
  // ...
  s : string;
begin
  s := ARequestInfo.CustomHeaders.Values['Origin']; < always empty
  // rest of the code here...
end;
```

## EDIT I found the solution:

```
s := ARequestInfo.RawHeaders.Values['origin'];
```

Just use `RawHeaders`.

Comment: You should have posted your edit as an answer instead.  You are allowed to answer your own question.  In any case, just to clarify, `CustomHeaders` is used when creating a new message (a request on the client side, a response on the server side).  `RawHeaders` is used when reading a message (a response on the client side, a request on the server side).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Cool, i'll do it next time. Thanks for the explanation. There shouldn't be customheaders on a request then and only on the response i think.

Answer (score 1):

```
ARequestInfo.RawHeaders.Values['origin'];
```

Instead of using `CustomHeader` I have to use `RawHeaders`.
Custom headers are user when creating the response and Raw Headers are the ones send by the browser/app that sent the request.